# catkin_make is laways trying to make one specfic package

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, ubuntu-16.04, ros, catkin

I need help with this, please.

The problem started when I tried making a new package in X workspace:

1. went to the source file of X package
2. created a new folder (Y) and an src folder in it.
3. catkin_make in the src folder of the Y package.
4. I edted the cmakelists file.
5. created a pacakage.xml

I faced an issue when compiling this package (I don't care about it anymore)

The issue I'm facing now is, whatever workspace I go to and try to run catkin_make I'm getting the same cmakelists file as in package Y I created in a different workspace, and all the other packages in the src file of this workspace are not compiled !!!
which is this one:

```
project(scaled_icp)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

#find_package(catkin_simple REQUIRED)
#catkin_simple(ALL_DEPS_REQUIRED)


# Adding PCL lib
find_package(PCL 1.8 REQUIRED)
# Setting include, lib directories and definitions 
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS} )
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS} )

 
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -fopenmp -std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")


# set(HEADERS
  
# )

set(SOURCES
  #src/scaled_icp.cpp
  
)


#cs_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} )

# Executables
################################################################################

#cs_add_executable(optimized_icp src/scaled_icp.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(optimized_icp ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})


################################################################################

#cs_install()
#cs_export()
```

I tried removing package y completely from workspace X !!
I also tried removing the build and devel files from the workspace but still the same issue!
But the same issue appears in all the workspaces!

This is the output of catkin_make in any workspace

```
Base path: /home/ubuntu/3DClustering
Source space: /home/ubuntu/3DClustering/src
Build space: /home/ubuntu/3DClustering/build
Devel space: /home/ubuntu/3DClustering/devel
Install space: /home/ubuntu/3DClustering/install
Creating symlink "/home/ubuntu/3DClustering/src/CMakeLists.txt" pointing to "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake"
WARNING: Package name "Mission_Management" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.
WARNING: Package name "URX" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/ubuntu/3DClustering/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/ubuntu/3DClustering/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ubuntu/3DClustering/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/ubuntu/3DClustering/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Checking for module 'eigen3'
--   Found eigen3, version 3.2.92
-- Found eigen: /usr/include/eigen3  
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found Boost: /usr/include (found suitable version "1.58.0", minimum required is "1.40.0") found components: system filesystem thread date_time iostreams serialization chrono atomic regex 
-- Checking for module 'libopenni'
--   Found libopenni, version 1.5.4.0
-- Found openni: /usr/lib/libOpenNI.so  
-- Checking for module 'libopenni2'
--   No package 'libopenni2' found
-- Could NOT find OpenNI2 (missing: OPENNI2_LIBRARY OPENNI2_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
** WARNING ** io features related to openni2 will be disabled
-- Could NOT find ensenso (missing: ENSENSO_LIBRARY ENSENSO_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** io features related to ensenso will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DAVIDSDK (missing: DAVIDSDK_LIBRARY DAVIDSDK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** io features related to davidSDK will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DSSDK (missing: _DSSDK_LIBRARIES) 
** WARNING ** io features related to dssdk will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to pcap will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to png will be disabled
-- Found libusb-1.0: /usr/include  
** WARNING ** io features related to libusb-1.0 will be disabled
-- Checking for module 'flann'
--   Found flann, version 1.8.4
-- Found Flann: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflann_cpp_s.a  
-- Checking for module 'libopenni2'
--   No package 'libopenni2' found
-- Could NOT find OpenNI2 (missing: OPENNI2_LIBRARY OPENNI2_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to openni2 will be disabled
-- Could NOT find ensenso (missing: ENSENSO_LIBRARY ENSENSO_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to ensenso will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DAVIDSDK (missing: DAVIDSDK_LIBRARY DAVIDSDK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to davidSDK will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DSSDK (missing: _DSSDK_LIBRARIES) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to dssdk will be disabled
-- Could NOT find RSSDK (missing: _RSSDK_LIBRARIES) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to rssdk will be disabled
-- Found qhull: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqhull.so  
-- looking for PCL_COMMON
-- Found PCL_COMMON: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_common.so  
-- looking for PCL_OCTREE
-- Found PCL_OCTREE: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_octree.so  
-- looking for PCL_IO
-- Found PCL_IO: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_io.so  
-- looking for PCL_KDTREE
-- Found PCL_KDTREE: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_kdtree.so  
-- looking for PCL_SEARCH
-- Found PCL_SEARCH: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_search.so  
-- looking for PCL_SAMPLE_CONSENSUS
-- Found PCL_SAMPLE_CONSENSUS: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_sample_consensus.so  
-- looking for PCL_FILTERS
-- Found PCL_FILTERS: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_filters.so  
-- looking for PCL_2D
-- Found PCL_2D: /usr/local/include/pcl-1.8  
-- looking for PCL_GEOMETRY
-- Found PCL_GEOMETRY: /usr/local/include/pcl-1.8  
-- looking for PCL_FEATURES
-- Found PCL_FEATURES: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_features.so  
-- looking for PCL_ML
-- Found PCL_ML: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_ml.so  
-- looking for PCL_SEGMENTATION
-- Found PCL_SEGMENTATION: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_segmentation.so  
-- looking for PCL_VISUALIZATION
-- Found PCL_VISUALIZATION: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_visualization.so  
-- looking for PCL_SURFACE
-- Found PCL_SURFACE: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_surface.so  
-- looking for PCL_REGISTRATION
-- Found PCL_REGISTRATION: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_registration.so  
-- looking for PCL_KEYPOINTS
-- Found PCL_KEYPOINTS: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_keypoints.so  
-- looking for PCL_TRACKING
-- Found PCL_TRACKING: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_tracking.so  
-- looking for PCL_RECOGNITION
-- Found PCL_RECOGNITION: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_recognition.so  
-- looking for PCL_STEREO
-- Found PCL_STEREO: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_stereo.so  
-- looking for PCL_OUTOFCORE
-- Found PCL_OUTOFCORE: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_outofcore.so  
-- looking for PCL_PEOPLE
-- Found PCL_PEOPLE: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_people.so  
-- Found PCL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;-lpthread;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_iostreams.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_atomic.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_common.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_common.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_octree.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_octree.so;/usr/lib/libOpenNI.so;vtkChartsCore;vtkCommonColor;vtkCommonCore;vtksys;vtkCommonDataModel;vtkCommonMath;vtkCommonMisc;vtkCommonSystem;vtkCommonTransforms;vtkCommonExecutionModel;vtkFiltersGeneral;vtkCommonComputationalGeometry;vtkFiltersCore;vtkInfovisCore;vtkFiltersExtraction;vtkFiltersStatistics;vtkImagingFourier;vtkImagingCore;vtkalglib;vtkRenderingContext2D;vtkRenderingCore;vtkFiltersGeometry;vtkFiltersSources;vtkRenderingFreeType;vtkfreetype;vtkzlib;vtkDICOMParser;vtkDomainsChemistry;vtkIOLegacy;vtkIOCore;vtkIOXMLParser;vtkexpat;vtkDomainsChemistryOpenGL2;vtkRenderingOpenGL2;vtkIOImage;vtkmetaio;vtkjpeg;vtkpng;vtktiff;vtkglew;vtkFiltersAMR;vtkIOXML;vtkParallelCore;vtkFiltersFlowPaths;vtkFiltersGeneric;vtkFiltersHybrid;vtkImagingSources;vtkFiltersHyperTree;vtkFiltersImaging;vtkImagingGeneral;vtkFiltersModeling;vtkFiltersParallel;vtkFiltersParallelImaging;vtkFiltersPoints;vtkFiltersProgrammable;vtkFiltersSMP;vtkFiltersSelection;vtkFiltersTexture;vtkFiltersVerdict;verdict;vtkGeovisCore;vtkInfovisLayout;vtkImagingHybrid;vtkInteractionStyle;vtkInteractionWidgets;vtkImagingColor;vtkRenderingAnnotation;vtkRenderingVolume;vtkViewsCore;vtkproj4;vtkIOAMR;vtkhdf5_hl;vtkhdf5;vtkIOEnSight;vtkIOExodus;vtkexoIIc;vtkNetCDF;vtkNetCDF_cxx;vtkIOExport;vtkRenderingGL2PSOpenGL2;vtkgl2ps;vtkIOGeometry;vtkIOImport;vtkIOInfovis;vtklibxml2;vtkIOLSDyna;vtkIOMINC;vtkIOMovie;vtkoggtheora;vtkIONetCDF;vtkIOPLY;vtkIOParallel;vtkjsoncpp;vtkIOParallelXML;vtkIOSQL;vtksqlite;vtkIOTecplotTable;vtkIOVideo;vtkImagingMath;vtkImagingMorphological;vtkImagingStatistics;vtkImagingStencil;vtkInteractionImage;vtkRenderingContextOpenGL2;vtkRenderingImage;vtkRenderingLOD;vtkRenderingLabel;vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL2;vtkViewsContext2D;vtkViewsInfovis;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_io.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_io.so;optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflann_cpp_s.a;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflann_cpp_s.a;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_kdtree.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_kdtree.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_search.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_search.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_sample_consensus.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_sample_consensus.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_filters.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_filters.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_features.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_features.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_ml.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_ml.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_segmentation.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_segmentation.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_visualization.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_visualization.so;optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqhull.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqhull.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_surface.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_surface.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_registration.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_registration.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_keypoints.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_keypoints.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_tracking.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_tracking.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_recognition.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_recognition.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_stereo.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_stereo.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_outofcore.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_outofcore.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_people.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_people.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;-lpthread;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_iostreams.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_atomic.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so;optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqhull.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqhull.so;/usr/lib/libOpenNI.so;optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflann_cpp_s.a;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflann_cpp_s.a;vtkChartsCore;vtkCommonColor;vtkCommonCore;vtksys;vtkCommonDataModel;vtkCommonMath;vtkCommonMisc;vtkCommonSystem;vtkCommonTransforms;vtkCommonExecutionModel;vtkFiltersGeneral;vtkCommonComputationalGeometry;vtkFiltersCore;vtkInfovisCore;vtkFiltersExtraction;vtkFiltersStatistics;vtkImagingFourier;vtkImagingCore;vtkalglib;vtkRenderingContext2D;vtkRenderingCore;vtkFiltersGeometry;vtkFiltersSources;vtkRenderingFreeType;vtkfreetype;vtkzlib;vtkDICOMParser;vtkDomainsChemistry;vtkIOLegacy;vtkIOCore;vtkIOXMLParser;vtkexpat;vtkDomainsChemistryOpenGL2;vtkRenderingOpenGL2;vtkIOImage;vtkmetaio;vtkjpeg;vtkpng;vtktiff;vtkglew;vtkFiltersAMR;vtkIOXML;vtkParallelCore;vtkFiltersFlowPaths;vtkFiltersGeneric;vtkFiltersHybrid;vtkImagingSources;vtkFiltersHyperTree;vtkFiltersImaging;vtkImagingGeneral;vtkFiltersModeling;vtkFiltersParallel;vtkFiltersParallelImaging;vtkFiltersPoints;vtkFiltersProgrammable;vtkFiltersSMP;vtkFiltersSelection;vtkFiltersTexture;vtkFiltersVerdict;verdict;vtkGeovisCore;vtkInfovisLayout;vtkImagingHybrid;vtkInteractionStyle;vtkInteractionWidgets;vtkImagingColor;vtkRenderingAnnotation;vtkRenderingVolume;vtkViewsCore;vtkproj4;vtkIOAMR;vtkhdf5_hl;vtkhdf5;vtkIOEnSight;vtkIOExodus;vtkexoIIc;vtkNetCDF;vtkNetCDF_cxx;vtkIOExport;vtkRenderingGL2PSOpenGL2;vtkgl2ps;vtkIOGeometry;vtkIOImport;vtkIOInfovis;vtklibxml2;vtkIOLSDyna;vtkIOMINC;vtkIOMovie;vtkoggtheora;vtkIONetCDF;vtkIOPLY;vtkIOParallel;vtkjsoncpp;vtkIOParallelXML;vtkIOSQL;vtksqlite;vtkIOTecplotTable;vtkIOVideo;vtkImagingMath;vtkImagingMorphological;vtkImagingStatistics;vtkImagingStencil;vtkInteractionImage;vtkRenderingContextOpenGL2;vtkRenderingImage;vtkRenderingLOD;vtkRenderingLabel;vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL2;vtkViewsContext2D;vtkViewsInfovis (Required is at least version "1.8") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX


-- Build files have been written to: /home/ubuntu/3DClustering/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/ubuntu/3DClustering/build"
####
```

Any help is appreciated

Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved

For some reason, I don't know how, a file in `/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake` called `toplevel.cmake` was changed to exactly the cmakelists file I was always getting.

The solution is to delete the cmakelists file from the src folder of your workspace and the build and devel files.

Then re-install ros catkin using

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-indigo-catkin
```

Note: change the ros distribution (indigo) to the one that suites you.

Now you can run `catkin_make`.